Help me find a practical product that implements Zero Knowledge Proofs and solves an actual problem in the blockchain context
I'll explain in broad terms what I'm trying to do. I'm writing a security thesis on Zero Knoweledge Proofs and my basic idea is to find a solution to the privacy problem in the blockchain through the development of something (I'm not sure what yet) and I'm doing some brainstorming with other devs around the web to figure it out.
I would like to incorporate smart contract auditing concepts also, into this practical solution.
For example: I thought of a sort of circuit to create zero knowledge audits, what do you think? here an example: zkPoEX

Could you suggest me some ideas or advice?

Even just a little suggestion from you would be really helpful, thank you
